# I want to create a event when I click on the title after live search to get the all the information and Star Wars character information

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

My goal is to create a live search function, to seek title, directors and open crawls, then clickable event on title to show information, and a clickable event on the characters.
    the problem I have is how to create the event and how to get the name of the characters and not just the links. When I iterate through the characters I just get the links.

```
<!-- The html for the live search  -->
 <form action="" id="searchArea">
<!-- The input for searching  -->
 <input type="search" id="search">

 </form>
//the data from jquery will present here
<div id="update">
</div>
<!-- closing  -->

//Jquery Document
    $(function(){

// create a keyup 
   $('#search').keyup(function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    //getting the search value from input
var searchTerm = $('#search').val();
 //insensitive case
var exp = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i');

 //getting the swapi film data
 $.getJSON("https://swapi.dev/api/films/", function (data) {//

 //creating a output future values of data
    var output = '<ul>'  

    //iterate through data.results with $.each
    $.each(data.results, function (key, value) { 

        //if statment for searching the title, director, opening crawal
if((value.title.search(exp)!= -1) || (value.director.search(exp)!= -1) || (value.opening_crawl.search(exp)!= -1)){
 //create a list 
//output with, title, director, opening crawl and characters 
    output += '<li>';
    output+='<h4>'+value.title+'</h4>' //need a clickable event for to get the charachters data and not just the links
    output+='<li>'+value.director+'</li>'
    output+='<p>'+value.opening_crawl+'</p>'
    output+='</li>';
}
    });
 //closing the ul
    output += '</ul>'
    $('#update').html(output);
    //output to html 


    }//json



);//key up



});
```

}); //doc.ready

Answer (score 0):

To be able to identify the title you clicked on you first need to add an identifier to the title. I am sure in the received data from the API there is an unique id for each title you get. Lets assume its called titleId. So now you add the id to your titles

```
output+='<h4 id="'+value.titleId+'">'+value.title+'</h4>';
```

After you have added the output to the DOM you can add a click event to all titles

```
$('#update').html(output);
$('h4').on('click', function()
{
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); // here we get our titleId
    // here we have to do our next action
}
```

To get the titles details you need another API call. I guess there must be a call to fetch detailed information from one title by its unique id.
This you should find out first. Then do this API call and show the titles details same way as you fetched and showed the title list.

Comment: i made this, but when i click on the title for a movie, the same charachters are showing up for every movie @Claus Bönnhoff

Comment: $('h4').on('click', function()
    {
    // console.log($(this).attr('id')); // here we get our titleId
    // here we have to do our next action

   $.getJSON("https://swapi.dev/api/people/",
       function (data) {

            let show = '<ul>'
        $.each(data.results, function (index, value) { 
        
             
            show+= '<li>'+value.name+'</li>'
            
        
        });
        
        show+= '</ul>'; 
        $('#info').html(show);  
        
       }
   );


})